# checking for set gpr?

Tags: php

What would be best practice in check for set get/post/request?

right now i am doing

```
if(!isset($_GET['account']) || !isset($_GET['ssid']) || !isset($_GET['mssid']) || !isset($_GET['max'])) { die("missing info"); }
if($_GET['account'] == "" || $_GET['ssid'] == "" || $_GET['mssid'] == "" || $_GET['max'] == "") { die("missing info"); }
```

I assume this is horrendous and very bad to do... can't seem to figure out the 'accepted' way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one way is to create a function that accepts an array, and a superglobal to check against, for completeness:

```
function arrayIsset(Array $keys, $array){
    $notSet = array();
    foreach($keys as $key){
        if(!isset($array[$key] || empty($array[$key]){
            $notSet[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return empty($notSet)
        ? true
        : $notSet;
}

$valid = arrayIsset(array('account', 'ssid', 'mssid'), $_GET);
```

If the values are all set and non-empty, it returns true, otherwise it returns an array of keys for missing values.

---

Based on your comments to **Felix Kling**; In addition to verifying whether a value is set/empty, you'll want to perform more robust validation techniques. There's a plethora available, both core (filters) and third party.

---

Though this doesn't cover Filters, string based validation is easy with Regex:

```
function validateArray(Array $validators, Array $array){

    foreach($validators as $key => $regex){

        if(!isset($array[$key])
        || empty($array[$key])
        || !preg_match($regex, $array[$key])){

            //failed

        }

    }

}

$isValid = validateArray(array(
    // alphanumeric, must start with alpha
    'username'       => '#^ [a-z] [a-z0-9]* $#Dix',
    // numeric 3 digits, space, 6 digits
    'account_number' => '#^ [0-9]{3} \s [0-9]{6} $#Dix',
), $_GET);
```

You can get really fancy with complicated regular expressions, but the aforementioned filters may be a better solution, depending on the level of complexity you wish to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, how would I handle per-field validation though? Such as $_GET['account'] being less than x number?

edit: min_range, max_range on filter_validate_int, sweet

Comment: Well, using a combination of typecasting, and Regex/filters, you can likely achieve the validation functionality you're looking for. I'll amend my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the fields you want to test, they might always be set (like text fields).

A nicer way of doing this would be:

```
$fields = array('account', 'ssid', 'mssid', 'max');

$error = array();
foreach($fields as $field) {
    if(!isset($_GET[$field]) || empty($_GET[$field])) {
        $error[] = $value;
    }
}

if(!empty($error)) {
    echo 'Error: Missing data for ', implode(',', $error);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: They may or may not be set, and I want to cast (int) or something on each field, in addition to having account be an integer less than 32000 and none of them being zero. Should I just toss an if{} inside that foreach or is that another bad thing?

Comment: This is all accepting user input too, so is (int)$var enough for "security" if I always assume it is a "real number"? or should I additionally sanitize it?

Comment: @jmoon: Well, there is nothing wrong with checking it inside the loop. Of course if you only want to compare one field against another number, then you should do this separately. Converting all input to integers should be save enough, but if an input cannot be converted, it will be converted to `0`, so you might not be able to decide whether it is invalid or really `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidier looking method. It checks to see if each key is present and contains a non-empty value:

```
foreach (array('account','ssid','mssid','max') as $param)
{
  if (!isset($_GET[$param]) || (isset($_GET[$param] && empty($_GET[$param])))
  {
    // exit or handle errors
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't believe the `in` syntax is valid in PHP; That's javascripty :) `foreach(array('foo', 'bar', 'baz') as $key){}`

Comment: @TomcatExodus Ouch, that's what I get for coding python all morning! Edited.